# Possible for a TCP socket to break so that it's still receiving but can no longer send?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, routes

Been programming with sockets for 15 years, and never run into this before.

Running a standard TCP socket server, clients connect to it, and messages are sent back and forth through the open socket.  This is a game server, where the client is acting in a game world that the server is running.  This server has handled 1.6 million such socket sessions over the past 3 months.

Server is logging messages that are received from the client.  Client is logging messages received from the server, and also logging messages that it sends to the server.

I just got a bug report from an end user where they had what seemed like a lost connection issue part-way through their session, and looking at the logs, it looks like the connection broke in one direction only.  The client's sends were not getting through, even though the server's sends kept getting through just fine.

After many messages back-and-forth for many minutes, the server receives one final message from this client, and then receives nothing more through that socket.  The client, on the other hand, continued to receive messages from the server the whole time, and continued sending messages to the server the whole time (from it's perspective---these were small messages, and perhaps were just piling up in the send buffer).

The server eventually detected that the client was idle, sent a goodbye message, and closed the connection.  The client even got the goodbye message.

This process lasted 18 seconds (from the time the server received the last message from the client, to the time it sent the goodbye message).

Question:  is this behavior possible for a TCP socket?  Where it breaks or stalls in one direction only?

I'm thinking about the acks that are supposed to be going through.  If the client->server route is broken, then the server won't be getting acks anymore.  So that means the server will be resending all packets over and over after a timeout.  But that doesn't mean it will stop sending new packets.  The client would also not be getting any acks back for the packets it is sending, but for a different reason (the packets aren't getting through at all, so the server can't ack them), so it would also be timing out and resending.

Maybe this isn't a TCP question as much as a network routing question.  Can a 2-way route break in one way only?

Comment: "_Can a 2-way route break in one way only?_" There is really no such thing as a two-way route. Packets are routed one at a time, regardless of any other packets. It is certainly possible for a router to have a route in only one direction, and there is also asymmetric routing where the path one way is different than the path in the other direction.

Comment: A TCP connection is actually two "channels": incoming and outgoing (the initial 3-way handshake sets them up). It´s possible to have only one "channel" up, the other one having been closed (for example a client shutting down the outgoing "channel" and just keep waiting for a final ok from the server).

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible for a socket to stop sending while continuing to receive. Look at `shutdown()`, which can close the send and receive channels independently or together.  A "graceful" disconnect involves first shutting down the send channel (which sends a `FIN` to the other party), then read until a peer disconnect/error is detected, then finally close the socket.

Comment: "*the client ... continued sending messages to the server the whole time (from it's perspective---these were small messages, and perhaps were just piling up in the send buffer)*" - that is a possibility, yes. Though the buffer will flush when full, or sending is idle. If you need to send many small messages frequently, you might consider enabling the socket's `TCP_NODELAY` option via `setsockopt()`.

Comment: Yeah, using TCP_NODELAY already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's likely a routing problem. The other comments above regarding unidirectional traffic only apply in the face of a `shutdown(2)` which presumably you would be aware of, since your application has to do that explicitly.

The routing could have been different in the two directions (as @RonMaupin noted). Or it could be that there was simply a large amount of congestion in one direction at some intermediate router. Either situation can result in packet drops.

In the face of dropped packets like this, the two sides will continue to retry their transmissions due to not receiving ACKs (which I think you've correctly described). The initial retransmission time is based on the approximate round-trip time calculated by each endpoint machine. Then there is an exponential backoff for subsequent retransmits -- see for example http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_time.htm#21_2 for explanation. The result is an eventual timeout.

Given the exponential backoff and some number of retransmits (that number is platform-specific and often configurable), it typically takes longer than 18 seconds before your local network stack declares a session dead. But it sounds like your application may have short-circuited this process with its own timeout (which seems reasonable for a game server).

I suspect you've never seen this before because in general the route is the same in both directions, and when a router is "down", it's down in both directions.

Comment: Thank you!  This sets my mind at ease.  I was assuming this was a routing issue outside of my control, but I just wanted a second opinion.